# Ssh and fips mode

Tags: openssl, openssh, fips

I am working on a networking device that needs to meet fips 140-2 level 2. ( runs on Ubuntu )

As for ssh, is it enough to limit the ciphers to those "allowed" by fips or should we patch openssh to use openssl fips api?

Comment: who do you need to satisfy?

Comment: do you need to achieve FIPS compliancy of ssh server that you run on your machine?

Comment: No, I have to satisfy FIPS 140-2 level 2 for a netwrokgin device.
We have an internal requirment for remote log-in over ssh